# Why did the Borg name Locutus?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

The other Borg get names like 4th of 12, adjunct matrix blah blah. So why did Captain Picard get a *name* when he was assimilated, instead of a numerical code / designation like all the other drones?

Comment: If you name a drone, you just end up getting attached to them. Which the Borg Queen totally did with Picard!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Giving him a name would make it easier for him to perform his primary function as an [intermediary in the assimilation of Earth](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Locutus_of_Borg), giving him a slightly more human quality than other Borg had:

> The Borg intended to use Picard as an intermediary, a spokesman for the Human race in order to facilitate the assimilation of Earth in order to make the process as quick and efficient (or as perfect, if you keep the Borg's driving force in mind) as possible with the fewest number of casualties on both sides.

It was also later revealed in [*First Contact*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek%3a_First_Contact) that the [Borg Queen](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Borg_Queen) had other plans for him than that of a lowly drone:

> It was later revealed that the Borg Queen herself was onboard the cube
>   to oversee Picard's assimilation into Locutus. She had intended for
>   Picard to become her equal counterpart, but when Picard refused to
>   give himself willingly and accept his assimilation, the Queen was
>   forced to turn Locutus into just another drone.

I guess being the Queen's consort entitles you to more than just a number.

Comment: If Patrick Stewart tells you to do something, you do it.

Comment: Now the bigger question - why did they give him such a creepy name?  "Hey guys, it's Frank.  We Borg are going to come down and chill".  Frank > Locutus.

Comment: Not very good at languages, are you.  "Locutus" is from the same Latin root for "talk."  loquor, loqui, locutus.  Which lives in various English words like "loquacious"

Comment: Just to add an additional theory to this. ST: Picard, Season 2 adds a potential explanation for why the Queen would want to turn Picard into a sort of equal. Spoilers follow.

The Jurati Borg have almost certainly contacted the "real" Borg - and they were not absorbed by the "real" Borg, who certainly would have wanted to do so. They likely learned of Jurati's friendship with Picard. Jurati likely tried to explain the value of friendship among equals. Thus, the "real" Queen, jealous/curious, decided to "befriend" Picard too. Locutus is her sick attempt to replicate Jurati's friendship.

Answer (score 57):

Locutus is not a name, it is his function. "Locutus" came from Latin and means "the one who speaks" like in the word locutor.

Picard was not Locutus of Borg, he is more like **the** Locutus of Borg, but the Locutus could be anyone else. They choose Picard to do that because he was the "locutus" of the Enterprise on their first encounter.

Comment: In the Star Trek novel The Return, the Romulan Borg representative is called Vox, I guess for the same reason.

Comment: "Locutus est" - it is spoken. "Locutus" sounds better than "locutor".

Comment: Yep, it's the passive form.

Comment: Borg's "Mouth of Sauron"

Comment: Didn't think they (the writers) were that well read.

Comment: If that's the case, then why do the Borg continue referring to Picard as "Locutus" after the incident?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

Also the name "locutus" is latin for spoken; which is what Picard did for the borg, he served as an intermediary—speaker—for them.