# Why does the Borg Queen have a gender?

Tags: star-trek, borg

As I just [answered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5660/do-borg-have-sexual-reproduction/5661#5661), Borg don't have sexual reproduction.

The Borg Queen seems to have replaceable bodies.

So why does she even *have* a gender (e.g. Borg Queen vs. Borg Leader)? She does have one - aside from the name; She keeps trying to turn males into her consorts (Locutus/Picard, then [Data](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/why-did-the-borg-name-locutus/5654#5654)).

One possible guess is that show creators trying to parallel her to an insect queen. But this seems inconsistent - she should have been genderless.

Comment: [Fan serice?](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fan%20service)

Comment: Well, _does_ she have a gender? If she has no sexual organs. Are you sure you're not just letting your biases show, and making assumptions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no in-Universe answer.  The Borg Queen was simply there to be a temptress and, yes, to draw parallels to insects as you pointed out.

One speculative thought is this: Whatever Species 0 (original Borg species) was, she was a member and was the driving force behind their creation of the Collective.

The bodies fashioned for her could then be patterned on her original form, and she could be the 'personality' of the Collective.

It's speculation, but it's the only explanation I can think of that fits the facts.

Comment: Wouldn't the Borg Queen be "Species 1"?

Comment: While I don't think the species number for the Queen in First Contact was mentioned, the Queen in Voyager does state that she was from Species X (I want to say 124, but I don't recall for certain right now)

Comment: I'd go with zero, them going with high-tech and computers where collections, lists and arrays all generally start at 0 (except where artificially bumped to 1 to feel more "natural" such as in the archaic VB6 language).

Comment: @eidylon - there are plenty of languages using 1. There's a relevant Q on StacjOverflow though I'm too lazy to find it to link

Comment: I thought the [Borg Queen](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Borg_Queen) revealed herself to be a member of [Species 125](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Species_125) towards the end of the series?

Comment: @DampeS8N: You may very well be correct.  My theory could still stand, however, if the full collective didn't exist at that point, or if she was lying.

Comment: @DVK, huh... did not know that. I've gotten so used to seeing 0 in .NET, C++, Java, etc... I always just assumed "Classic" VB was one of the few (or the only) odd ball out in that regard! (*It did so much other stuff odd ball! LOL*)

Comment: It's like a virus or disease - it all starts with Patient Zero.

Answer (score 21):

I think the writers were trying to strengthen the connection to the hive, bee-like elements of the Borg Collective. In Star Trek: First Contact, it was revealed that Locutus was made to be both a connection to humanity, a species that the Borg were having trouble assimilating, AND be a companion to the Borg Queen.

The Queen having a gender makes sense because the Star Trek canon throughout the TNG run was not really able to deal with non-binary gender issues in a particularly thoughtful or open-minded way. Being either male or female remained the 'default' throughout the universe at this time, so a 'female' Queen to a 'male' Locutus makes sense in the (pretty narrow-minded) universe they had been writing within.

Comment: I thought TNG was the _only_ Star Trek series that actually delved into non male-female gendered/sexed societies. The binars seemed to be androgynous, and the J'naii were also an androgynous society, though shown in a less than positive light. I don't recall any other of the later series even broaching the issue.

Later series mention societies like the Vissians, Tholians, and Insectoids as reproducing asexually or requiring 3 sexes to reproduce, but these are usually mentioned in passing and seem more intended to make those species feel more exotic or alien (esp. the Tholians).

Answer (score 5):

While the real world answer may have been to draw parallels to insect hives, the in universe answer may be as simple as thats what gender the host body was.

As far as I know only two Borg leaders have been seen in Star Trek and while both of them were female that isn't really enough data to draw any solid conclusions off of, considering how long the collective had been around.

Answer (score 4):

The queen was initially of species 125, then got assimilated into the Borg queen.
It's never explained why she became a queen and not a leader. The only presumable thing is in nature if there is a large colony its 90% of the time led by a female and workers are male (bee's ants etc)
Although the Borg aren't insects, that's my only reason.

Just wanted to point out that the queen wasn't the first Borg and she wasn't species 0/1

Comment: With colonizing insects, the workers and the queen are both female. Drones are males. Typically, the only difference between a worker and a queen is development. In honey bees, for example, a female larvae that is fed a larger amount of royal jelly develops into a queen, while the female larvae that are fed the normal amount develop into workers. So here's the rub with this answer: it is factually incorrect on the insect thing, and gives no reference that the queen was a former member of species 125.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert on Star Trek even a little bit, but a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/why-does-the-borg-queen-have-a-gender#comment9087_5665) to one of the other answers links to [Species 125](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Species_125) from the Memory Alpha wiki, which says:

> In the [Star Trek: Legacy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Legacy) segment "The Origin of the Borg", it is stated that the collective found the females of certain species (likely referring to Species 125) displayed a mental prowess, enabling them to sift through thousands of thoughts and bring order to chaos.

*Star Trek: Legacy* was a video game, and I'm not sure where that falls in the Spectrum of Trek Canonicity, but this suggests an in-universe explanation: the trait which allowed the collective to have a queen at all had some connection to femaleness in its origin, and some aspect of that femaleness survived assimilation.

Answer (score 1):

In Star Trek: Destiny - the trilogy by David Mack - we learn that the Borg stem from a race known as Caeliar and come from a botched test to save human and Caeliar lives. We are not informed whether any of these develop to become the Borg Queen. However, we also learn that there is another Borg Queen that lords over a certain division of Borg. This leads to speculation that there could be multiple Borg Queens for each hypothetical hive.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why there is a female leader and not a genderless one

Comment: You might want to post an answer here: [What was the origin of Star Trek's Borg?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/426/what-was-the-origin-of-star-treks-borg)