# Why did Locutus not lose his hair?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

Borg drones lose hair soon after assimilation, and the Borg Queen told Seven of Nine after Seven's implants were removed that the humans made her in their image and gave her things like hair, and I take this to imply that the Borg Queen does not consider hair to be part of the Borg appearance. So why does Locutus still have hair after full assimilation?

[image: Picard / Locutus, with some hair on his head towards the back]

In contrast, Janeway did lose her hair, including eyebrows, after assimilation, though just like Picard, she did not remain Borg for very long and her implants were soon removed as well.

[image: Assimilated Janeway with no hair]

Is there an in-universe explanation of this?

Comment: Drone1: "Initiate standard shaving procedure?"
Drone2: "Negative. Subject appears to be be biologically self-shaving."

Comment: Locutus wasn't fully assimilated. He was meant to keep some humanity so he could act as a bridge between the Borg and the Federation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - q.v. Why does Locutus have a name? etc

Comment: [Why did the Borg name Locutus?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/why-did-the-borg-name-locutus)